# Add pods items to menus?

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I've created a pod type that I want to put under a menu item.

The only way I can figure out to do this is to manually add the links to the individual pods, but I'd like it to be more integrated than that.

Comment: Are you using the native WordPress Menu builder (Appeareances -> Menus)?

Comment: Yes, I am using the default menus.

Comment: at the top-right of the screen you should see: screen options, click on it and let me know if you can see your custom post type name and if it is checked

Comment: What content type are these Pods? If they are custom post type or custom taxonomy Pods, then @antonio83 is on the right track. If they are advanced content type Pods, than you will need to use the 'wp_nav_menu_items' filter, which I'll explain in a full answer.

Comment: Ok, the pod was in there, and checking it allowed me to add it to my menus. You should post that as the answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

at the top-right of the screen you should see: screen options, click on it and let me know if you can see your custom post type name and if it is checked